# Penalty function of multi-peak fit?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, regression, data-analysis

The question I have is about the answer from here by @Silvia: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting

I can only understand some of the code but the penalty function phenomena (which was demonstrated) looks interesting; how the sum squares of residuals decrease more slowly after the correct peak number. Where can I learn more about this statistical phenomena, and its limitations?
More importantly, how would one code the penalty function?